# In hive, count time between two time

Tags: sql, hql, hive

In hive, I have a table with lots columns, which two of them are begin_time, end_time.

I need to count the number on the each time

a piece of the table is this:

```
begin_time                  end_time
2011.04.26 10:19:06^A2011.04.26 10:20:22
2011.04.26 10:19:08^A2011.04.26 10:21:49
2011.04.26 10:19:08^A2011.04.26 11:18:46
2011.04.26 10:19:09^A2011.04.26 12:08:36
2011.04.26 10:19:09^A2011.04.26 11:00:16
2011.04.26 10:19:11^A2011.04.26 10:19:17
2011.04.26 10:19:12^A2011.04.26 10:46:21
2011.04.26 10:19:13^A2011.04.26 10:55:43
2011.04.26 10:19:17^A2011.04.26 10:19:41
2011.04.26 10:19:18^A2011.04.26 10:34:41
```

the result I want is how many people is in on a specific time.

e.g. on 2011.04.26 10:19:08, there 3 visitor on course there one in 19:06, and 2 in 19:08.

and 2011.04.26 10:19:18 is 9, course ten but one leave on 2011.04.26 10:19:17

the desired result for piece is

```
2011.04.26 10:19:06 1
2011.04.26 10:19:08 3
2011.04.26 10:19:09 5
2011.04.26 10:19:11 6
2011.04.26 10:19:12 7
2011.04.26 10:19:13 8
2011.04.26 10:19:17 9
2011.04.26 10:19:18 9
```

Any help is much appreciated and welcome.

Comment: I tried it in hql using select, but it seems hard to do this. And in c/c++ the magnitude like array with 100k seems too large.

Comment: `2011.04.26 10:19:17 9` ----> `2011.04.26 10:19:17 8`

Comment: On 2011.04.26 10:19:17 there are 9 users, except one out on 10:19:17. why is 8?

Comment: seems same question to
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641072/hadoop-hive-count-concurrency/16686255#16686255

Comment: yes, I implement it in c. But need in hadoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sql:

```
SELECT v.begin_time AS "time",
       COUNT(*) AS "visitors"
  FROM visits v
  JOIN visits o
       ON v.begin_time BETWEEN o.begin_time AND o.end_time
 GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: Sadly, I don't think this will work in Hive. From the Hive language manual: "Hive does not support join conditions that are not equality conditions as it is very difficult to express such conditions as a map/reduce job." https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-joins.html

Comment: @LukasVermeer, oh, thanks.  I saw the "sql" tag before writing this.